# Чпу без htaccess, чем это чревато?

Tags: php, чпу

Здравствуйте товарищи! Решил реализовать **ЧПУ** без **.htaccess** следующим образом :

запрос будет таким : **mysite.zone/?/show_page/name/number**

```
<?php

preg_match_all('#\/([a-z0-9_]*)#', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $index_qs);

echo $index_qs[1][0];//show_page
echo $index_qs[1][1];//name
echo $index_qs[1][2];//number

?>
```

Вопрос : как относятся роботы поисковых систем к таким **URl** адресам? Какие возможные проблемы могут возникнуть при использовании таких **URL'ов**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как по мне - так ничем не чревато, разве что, не так красиво, как с .htaccess :]

Я бы на вашем месте сделал маршрутизатор, который бы вешал на каждый возможный урл свой экшн:]

Answer (score 1):

Ничем, только:

1. Всё-таки красивше будет mysite.zone/show_page/name/number (делается через 404)
2. При этом не надо забывать отдавать корректный 404 когда нужно